# Families of curves and fiber bundles.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider a family of curves of genus $g$ over a scheme $X$, 
$$ \mathcal{C}_g \to X $$

Is there a way one can interpret such a family as a fiber bundle over $X$?

Maybe with some extra conditions like being a flat, proper etc. morphism.

Comment: When g = 0 and assume the base field is algebraically closed, then it is possible to show that this becomes a fiber bundle. The proof involves the use of the fact that $H^1(\mathbb{P}^1, \mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{P}^1}) = 0$ and hence it can only work in genus 0 case. Look at the lemma and the proof in the answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2212997/geometric-fibers-mathbb-pn-vanishing-of-brauer-group-implies-projective-bu 
BTW what exactly do you mean by "interpret such a family"?

Comment: I mean is a family also a fiber bundle.

Comment: Maybe one should impose the condition that all the curves are isomorphic over closed points(atleast) otherwise one can find a family of elliptic curves over some open subset of affine line. Also if one assumes that the base field is $\mathbb{C}$ and the map is proper, smooth and $X$ is smooth, then we get via Grauert-Fischer theorem that this is a locally trivial family in the analytic sense. This will give some principal Aut(X)-bundle in a canonical fashion. Now maybe some GAGA machinery could be applied here to get that this is a fiber bundle in the algebraic sense in some cases.